# Why am I getting borders in outlook 2010 html emails

Tags: html, email, html-email

I think I have tried all of the tricks I have read about for getting rid of the spacing between table rows but nothing seems to work! My email looks good in gmail and on iphones and android phones. It is just outlook!

I am using mailchimp so there are other styles in my template, but even if I remove all of the styles I still get the same result.

Here is my HTML table:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  style="border-collapse: collapse; margin:0px; padding:0px;" width="600">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="border-collapse: collapse;" width="600" height="179">
                <a href="http://www.anzie.com/"><img align="left" alt="Gold Rush" height="179" src="https://d2q0qd5iz04n9u.cloudfront.net/_ssl/proxy.php/http/gallery.mailchimp.com/5513172da1aa95c4b84fdedba/images/ESSETIAL6_FALL_01.jpg" style="height: 179px;  width: 600px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;  display:block; vertical-align: bottom; float: left; " width="600" /></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="border-collapse: collapse;" width="600" height="25">
                <a href="http://www.anzie.com/viewall_gold.php"><img align="left" alt="Shop Gold" height="25" src="https://d2q0qd5iz04n9u.cloudfront.net/_ssl/proxy.php/http/gallery.mailchimp.com/5513172da1aa95c4b84fdedba/images/ESSETIAL6_FALL_02.1.jpg" style="height: 25px;  width: 600px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;  display:block; vertical-align: bottom; float: left; " width="600" /></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="border-collapse: collapse;">
            <td colspan="3" style="border-collapse: collapse;" width="600" height="200">
                <a href="http://www.anzie.com"><img align="left" alt="Gold Rush" height="200" src="https://d2q0qd5iz04n9u.cloudfront.net/_ssl/proxy.php/http/gallery.mailchimp.com/5513172da1aa95c4b84fdedba/images/ESSETIAL6_FALL_03.jpg" style="height: 200px;  width: 600px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;  display:block; vertical-align: bottom; float: left;" width="600" /></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                <a href="http://www.anzie.com/dew-drop-collection-etoile-mini-ring-moonstone-p-2454.html"><img align="left" alt="Vintage Accent Ring" height="221" src="https://d2q0qd5iz04n9u.cloudfront.net/_ssl/proxy.php/http/gallery.mailchimp.com/5513172da1aa95c4b84fdedba/images/ESSETIAL6_FALL_04.jpg" style="width: 226px; height: 221px;  display:block; vertical-align: bottom; float: left;" width="226" /></a></td>
            <td style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                <a href="http://www.anzie.com/aztec-earrings-studs-mini-moonstone-clear-topaz-p-2508.html"><img align="left" alt="Minature Studs" height="221" src="https://d2q0qd5iz04n9u.cloudfront.net/_ssl/proxy.php/http/gallery.mailchimp.com/5513172da1aa95c4b84fdedba/images/ESSETIAL6_FALL_05.jpg" style="height: 221px;  width: 159px;  display:block; vertical-align: bottom; float: left;" width="159" /></a></td>
            <td style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                <a href="http://www.anzie.com/royale-ring-round-moonstone-p-1919.html"><img align="left" alt="Heirloom Ring" height="221" src="https://d2q0qd5iz04n9u.cloudfront.net/_ssl/proxy.php/http/gallery.mailchimp.com/5513172da1aa95c4b84fdedba/images/ESSETIAL6_FALL_06.jpg" style="height: 221px;  width: 215px;  display:block; vertical-align: bottom; float: left;" width="215" /></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                <a href="http://www.anzie.com/dew-drop-collection-etoile-earrings-moonstone-p-2498.html"><img align="left" alt="Evening Earrings" height="324" src="https://d2q0qd5iz04n9u.cloudfront.net/_ssl/proxy.php/http/gallery.mailchimp.com/5513172da1aa95c4b84fdedba/images/evening_earrrings.jpg" style="height: 324px;  width: 226px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;  display:block; vertical-align: bottom; float: left;" width="226" /></a></td>
            <td style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                <a href="http://www.anzie.com/aztec-necklace-sun-pendant-moonstone-diamonds-p-2509.html"><img align="left" alt="Statement Pendant" height="324" src="https://d2q0qd5iz04n9u.cloudfront.net/_ssl/proxy.php/http/gallery.mailchimp.com/5513172da1aa95c4b84fdedba/images/neckalce_center.jpg" style="height: 324px;  width: 159px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;  display:block; vertical-align: bottom; float: left;" width="159" /></a></td>
            <td style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                <a href="http://www.anzie.com/dew-drop-collection-bubble-stackable-bangle-gold-set-p-2510.html"><img align="left" alt="Versatile Bangles" height="324" src="https://d2q0qd5iz04n9u.cloudfront.net/_ssl/proxy.php/http/gallery.mailchimp.com/5513172da1aa95c4b84fdedba/images/ESSETIAL6_FALL_09.jpg" style="height: 324px;  width: 215px;  display:block; vertical-align: bottom; float: left;" width="215" /></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                <img align="left" height="74" src="https://d2q0qd5iz04n9u.cloudfront.net/_ssl/proxy.php/http/gallery.mailchimp.com/5513172da1aa95c4b84fdedba/images/border_bottom_left.jpg" style="width: 226px; height: 74px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;  display:block; vertical-align: bottom; float: left;" width="226" /></td>
            <td style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                <img align="left" height="74" src="https://d2q0qd5iz04n9u.cloudfront.net/_ssl/proxy.php/http/gallery.mailchimp.com/5513172da1aa95c4b84fdedba/images/bottom_center.jpg" style="width: 159px; height: 74px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;  display:block; vertical-align: bottom; float: left;" width="159" /></td>
            <td style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                <a href="http://www.anzie.com/locations.php"><img align="left" alt="Locate Store" height="74" src="https://d2q0qd5iz04n9u.cloudfront.net/_ssl/proxy.php/http/gallery.mailchimp.com/5513172da1aa95c4b84fdedba/images/ESSETIAL6_FALL_10.jpg" style="height: 74px;  width: 215px;  display:block; vertical-align: bottom; float: left;" width="215" /></a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Try to split your rows into multiple tables instead of using "colspan". Personally I never use colspan/rowspan and my emails always  looks perfect (at least according to Litmus) :)

Comment: I separated it and I still have the same result unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

try removing `colspan` from the all `<td>`. Also, remove `width="600"` from the `tds`, so that it would take the width of the `img`